# Using Windows Authentication, not getting a popup

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication

In my program, I'm attempting to use Windows Authentication, which I have never used before and so am pretty confused. I've followed what I think I should do and what I've found in my google searches by adding this in my `Web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and my IIS settings look like this:

[image]

but whenever I run my website, it just loads up correctly when I believe I should be getting a popup that asks for my username/password. How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a popup if you try with Firefox, Seamonkey and probably Chrome. If you want a popup with the Internet Explorer, try this:

Tools | Internet options | Security | Local intranet (or some other zone) | Custom level | user authentication | Prompt for user name and password

EDIT: You an find Tools on the menu bar. If you don't see menu bar, open it by right click somewhere near tabs and enable Menu bar. See screenshots:

[image: Open menu bar]

[image: Internet options]

Comment: I'm using chrome, not sure why I'm not getting a popup, though, I'm getting on on Edge

Comment: Where do I access Tools, Internet options etc?

Comment: @sbattou see screenshots

Comment: @Tom it worked! Do you have similar steps for Edge?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't use Edge. However, you might try importing settings from the IE and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar just few days ago, what I did is following,
in my login form process

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public bool Login(string user, string password) {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR DOMAIN WITH ACTIVE DIRECTORY"))
        {
            return pc.ValidateCredentials(user, password);
        }
    }
```

I am hoping this helps you out! Best of luck!